# Install package (library) if not installed

Tags: r, installation, package

I am using a couple of packages in R, but I am running the script in a machine that may or may not have some/all of the packages installed already.

The packages are `zoo`, `quantmod`, `data.table`,..., and a bunch more.

This is what I have tried:
Is there any way of checking if each of these packages is installed, if not install it? I don't want R to waste time reinstalling any package that is already there.

This is what I have tried:

```
pckg = c("zoo", "tseries", "quantmod", "MASS", "graphics", "plyr", "data.table", "gridExtra") 

 is.installed <- function(mypkg){
    is.element(mypkg, installed.packages()[,1])
 } 

 for(i in 1:length(pckg)) {
    if (!is.installed(pckg[i])){
         install.packages(pckg[i])
     }
 }
```

Is there a better way of doing that?

Also, I need to **automatically set a mirror for the install**.I have no idea how to do so.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

I have this convenience function that I use instead of `library` which installs the package if it is missing, then `require`s it:

```
usePackage <- function(p) {
    if (!is.element(p, installed.packages()[,1]))
        install.packages(p, dep = TRUE)
    require(p, character.only = TRUE)
}
```

In case if you need to select CRAN mirror globally, here is one way to do it:

```
r <- getOption("repos")
r["CRAN"] <- "http://cran.us.r-project.org"
options(repos = r)
rm(r)
```

Comment: It seems to me that the behaviour of `require()` depends on the R editor. While `require()` works as described above in RKward, it did not using RStudio. Instead, RStudio gives a warning message.

Therefore `require(XXX) || install.packages("XXX")` is safer because it always works, regardless of the editor you are using.