# On-demand installation of packages

Tags: r, installation, package

Is there a "standard" way to load a package, and install it if it isn't installed yet? Something like

```
if (!is.installed(package))
    install(package)
library(package)
```

(pseudocode!), encapsulated in a neat function?

I'm usually having a hard time after wiping my private site library, which I do every now and then. If my scripts all used this "install-on-demand" facility, this would just happen automatically.

Comment: I use what you suggest with `is.installed <- function(mypkg) is.element(mypkg, installed.packages()[,1])`. Of course, I set `dependencies=TRUE`.

Comment: @Roland: So, no package that provides this functionality?

Comment: I do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19596359/install-package-library-if-not-installed/19598076#19598076

Answer (score 2):

Dason K. and I have [a package in the works on GitHub](https://github.com/trinker/pacman) that needs some testing and a bit of cleaning and eventually will be pushed to CRAN.  The function `p_load` in the package does this.

```
library(devtools)
install_github("trinker/pacman")
```

Comment: Thanks! Why don't you rather answer the linked question, now this is an official dupe? Also, how does `pacman` compare with [`packrat`](https://github.com/rstudio/packrat) and [`rbundler`](https://github.com/opower/rbundler)?

Comment: *bump* Why don't you re-post it here, where it might get more attention: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090169/elegant-way-to-check-for-missing-packages-and-install-them?lq=1

Comment: @krlmlr **pacman** does very different things than **packrat**.  The former works to improve workflow through more consistently named and compact acting functions while the later seems to be more focused on preserving a particular environment, both useful for different purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I see that other answers have been given but my preference would be:

```
 if ( !require('pkg') ) { install.packages('pkg', dependencies=TRUE);
                        require('pkg') }
```

If you want to suppress the warning, then add `quietly=TRUE` to the first `require` call. I suppose you could bundle this into a function, called, what? `insist`?

```
 insist <- function(pkg){
          if ( !require(pkg, character.only=TRUE) ) { 
                    install.packages(as.character(pkg), dependencies=TRUE)
          require(pkg, character.only=TRUE) }
                         }
```

(My major stumbling block: The first argument to require didn't seem to get evaluated unless `character.only=TRUE`. Took me several reads of the `?require` page to get this idea. Just slow, I guess.)